# Java Math Equation

Tags: java, math, equation, equation-solving

seems like I just have trouble getting the equation written down but im dealing with this question :

Write a program that prompts the user to enter the
side of a hexagon and displays its area. The formula for computing the area of a
hexagon is

[image]

A=area , a=side length

Here is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Areahexagon


{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    double s;
    Scanner sid = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter side's number for hexagons area");

  s = sid.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("The area is ");

    double area = ((Math.sqrt(3/3) / 2) + Math.Pow 2);
  System.out.println(distance);
  }
}
```

Comment: `(Math.sqrt(3/3)` ??

Comment: yeah the formula is as follows: 3 (square root) 3 / 2 (exponent 2 ) , please see this link to see what im talking about https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CAFA_enCA610CA610&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=formula%20for%20area%20of%20hexagon

Comment: but `(Math.sqrt(3/3) == (Math.sqrt(1)`

Comment: That's not even valid Java (Math.Pow 2), plus the fact that you don't use s in the area calculation should indicate something's not right.

Answer (score 6):

Try this formula

```
double area = (3*(Math.sqrt(3))*s*s)/2;
```

The formula for area of hexagon is 3 multiplied by sqrt of 3 multiplied by the side square and divided by 2. In this case, you are not using Math class correctly for getting square root of 3. Also, you are not getting square of the side in his code and instead using Math.Pow 2 - which is incorrect.